# Speed up iterations python

Tags: python, csv, iteration

I'm trying to parse data into a csv prior to a bulk transaction into Neo4j.  I'm using vast amounts of data in the relationships and wondered if anyone could help in speeding up the transactions below.  It's genomic data, with 2,000 samples, each with up to 3.5m variants per chromosome probably equating to about 40m variants, up to two rows per sample, so ~120,000,000,000 rows in total.  Currently it's taking me about 20 minutes per sample.  Does anyone have any suggestions on how to improve this:

```
import sys
import time
import datetime
import numpy as np
import allel
import zarr
import numcodecs
import os
import pandas
import csv
import math
import dask.array as da
vcf_directory = '/media/user/Seagate Backup Plus Drive/uk_alspac/'
zarr_path = vcf_directory + 'chroms.zarr'
callset = zarr.open_group(zarr_path, mode='r')
samples_fn = '/media/user/Seagate Backup Plus Drive/uk_alspac/phenotype_data/EGAZ00001016605_UK10K_ALSPAC_Phenotype_Data_August_2013_1867samples.txt'
panel = pandas.DataFrame.from_csv(samples_fn, sep='\t')
chrom_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,'X']
i = 0
j = 0
seq_tech = 'Illumina HiSeq 2000 (ILLUMINA)'
with open('/media/user/Seagate Backup Plus Drive/uk_alspac/Import_files/sample_variants.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
filewriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
filewriter.writerow([':START_ID(Sample)','type', 'hapA', 'hapB','genotype', 'seqtech', 'read_depth', 'phase_set','GP0','GP1','GP2','PL0','PL1','PL2', ':END_ID(Variant)'])
for chrom in chrom_list:
    print(chrom)
    datetime_object = datetime.datetime.now()
    print(datetime_object)
    sampledata = callset[chrom]['samples']
    samples = list(sampledata)
    variants = allel.VariantChunkedTable(callset[chrom]['variants'], names=['AC','AF_AFR', 'AF_AMR', 'AF_ASN', 'AF_EUR', 'AF_MAX', 'CGT', 'CLR', 'CSQ', 'DP', 'DP4', 'ESP_MAF', 'FILTER_LowQual', 'FILTER_MinHWE', 'FILTER_MinVQSLOD', 'FILTER_PASS', 'HWE', 'ICF', 'ID', 'IS', 'PC2', 'PCHI2', 'POS', 'PR', 'QCHI2', 'QUAL', 'REF', 'ALT', 'INDEL', 'SHAPEIT', 'SNP_ID', 'TYPE', 'UGT', 'VQSLOD', 'dbSNPmismatch', 'is_snp', 'numalt', 'svlen'], index='POS')
    pos = variants['POS'][:]
    SNPid = variants['ID'][:]
    ref = variants['REF'][:]
    alt = variants['ALT'][:]
    dp = variants['DP'][:]
    ac = variants['AC'][:]
    vartype = variants['TYPE'][:]
    svlen = variants['svlen'][:]
    qual = variants['QUAL'][:]
    vq = variants['VQSLOD'][:]
    numalt = variants['numalt'][:]
    csq = variants['CSQ'][:]
    vcfv = 'VCFv4.1'
    refv = 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/assembly/GCF_000001405.13/'
    calldata = callset[chrom]['calldata']
    dpz = calldata['DP']
    psz = calldata['PS']
    plz = calldata['PL']
    gpz = calldata['GP']
    gtz = calldata['GT']
    i = 0
    j = 0
    seq_tech = 'Illumina HiSeq 2000 (ILLUMINA)'
    for i in range(50):
        print("Chrom " + str(chrom) + "sample" + str(i))
        print(datetime_object)
        gt = gtz[:,i].tolist()
        hap1, hap2 = zip(*gt)
        dp = dpz[:, i]
        ps = psz[:, i]
        pl = plz[:, i]
        gp = gpz[:, i]
        subject = samples[i]
        for j in range(len(pos)): 
            h1 = int(hap1[j])
            h2 = int(hap2[j])
            read_depth = int(dp[j])
            ps1 = int(ps[j])
            PL0 = int(pl[j][0])
            PL1 = int(pl[j][1])
            PL2 = int(pl[j][2])        
            GP0 = float(gp[j][0])
            GP1 = float(gp[j][1])
            GP2 = float(gp[j][2])

            if h1 == 0 and h2 == 0:
                filewriter.writerow([subject,"Homozygous",h1 ,h2, str(h1) + '|' + str(h2), seq_tech, read_depth, ps1, GP0, GP1, GP2, PL0, PL1, PL2, str(chrom) + '-' + str(pos[j]) + ref[j]])
            elif h1 == 0 and h2 > 0:  
                filewriter.writerow([subject,"Heterozygous - Haplotype A",h1 ,'', str(h1) + '|' + str(h2), seq_tech, read_depth, ps1, GP0, GP1, GP2, PL0, PL1, PL2, str(chrom) + '-' + str(pos[j]) + ref[j]])
                filewriter.writerow([subject,"Heterozygous - Haplotype B",'',h2, str(h1) + '|' + str(h2), seq_tech, read_depth, ps1, GP0, GP1, GP2, PL0, PL1, PL2, str(chrom) + '-' + str(pos[j]) + alt[j][h2-1]])
            elif h1 > 0 and h2 == 0:
                filewriter.writerow([subject,"Heterozygous - Haplotype A",h1, '', str(h1) + '|' + str(h2), seq_tech, read_depth, ps1, GP0, GP1, GP2, PL0, PL1, PL2, str(chrom) + '-' + str(pos[j]) + alt[j][h1-1]])
                filewriter.writerow([subject,"Heterozygous - Haplotype B",'' ,h2, str(h1) + '|' + str(h2), seq_tech, read_depth, ps1, GP0, GP1, GP2, PL0, PL1, PL2, str(chrom) + '-' + str(pos[j]) + ref[j]])
            elif h1 == h2 and h1 > 0:
                filewriter.writerow([subject,"Homozygous",h1, h2, str(h1) + '|' + str(h2), seq_tech, read_depth, ps1, GP0, GP1, GP2, PL0, PL1, PL2, str(chrom) + '-' + str(pos[j]) + alt[j][h1-1]])     
            else:
                filewriter.writerow([subject,"Heterozygous - Haplotype A",h1,'', str(h1) + '|' + str(h2), seq_tech, read_depth, ps1, GP0, GP1, GP2, PL0, PL1, PL2, str(chrom) + '-' + str(pos[j]) + alt[j][h1-1]])
                filewriter.writerow([subject,"Heterozygous - Haplotype B",'',h2, str(h1) + '|' + str(h2), seq_tech, read_depth, ps1, GP0, GP1, GP2, PL0, PL1, PL2, str(chrom) + '-' + str(pos[j]) + alt[j][h2-1]])
```

It was all done a bit ad-hoc and I'm still new to python, so any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: `dp = dpz[:, i]
        ps = psz[:, i]
        pl = plz[:, i]
        gp = gpz[:, i]` and all list copies you are making inside a loop could be a bad idea depending on what you are trying to achieve....anyway SO is for problems, your code needs a several code review: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If this works, it would perhaps be more appropriate to ask in [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: At a guess, it's probably worth looking into and learning Pandas. That'll make the code look nicer, and is very likely to be (a lot) faster as well.

Comment: Do you comment the `print` commands when you run your code? Printing can make iterations very slowly...

Comment: @olinox14 only on completion of each sample and then each chromosome, but that should be 2000 x 23 so not that much in the grand scheme of things, but lets me see the progression.